# Stop SQL Server Management Studio from adding ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-server-2008

How do I prevent SQL Management Studio (10.50.2500.0) from adding this to the beginning of every stored procedure when I right-click/Modify?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

Neither of these settings are useful to me. ANSI_NULLS ON and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON is set on all my servers, DBs and connections I make. Besides that, I never use double quotes (I used brackets for reserved words) and all my nullable fields I properly use IS NULL when needed.

I delete the settings every time I edit a procedure. All my procedures properly have them set and that will never change in my environment. Verified by:

```
SELECT uses_ansi_nulls, uses_quoted_identifier
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = object_id( 'proc_name' )
```

Comment: I can't find a means to do so (You'd expect them to appear in `Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting`), but you probably don't want to remove them anyway (What problem are they causing you?)

Comment: Yeah, it seems like that should be the place. It's annoying. The only problem they cause me is that they are unnecessary and waste space. I updated the question to explain further.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure whether this counts as an answer or an unhelpful non-answer, but as Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested **you absolutely don't want SSMS to stop scripting these lines**. Because they are in the sql_modules table they form an integral part of the definition of the stored procedure, along with the SQL code itself. So they can't be "turned off" any more than your SQL code could.

If you create/alter a stored procedure from a connection that has a different `ANSI_NULLS` option value to that used when the stored procedure was created/defined, then you *change the behaviour of that stored procedure*, permanently!

It is for this reason that SSMS (and any half-decent SQL object scripting tool) will **always** output these lines - because if you remove them or change them, you are changing the definition of the stored procedure (removing them, particularly, is bad because it means that the behaviour of the stored procedure, depending on what connection it is published from, can vary).

Doing a quick google search for "ANSI_NULLS QUOTED_IDENTIFIER stored procedure", the top result is the following article that seems to explain the options, and their impact, very clearly: http://ranjithk.com/2010/01/10/understanding-set-quoted_identifier-onoff/

Comment: If someone didn't understand what they were doing, maybe these would be useful settings. And by removing them I'm only changing the definition of the stored procedure if my default is different than the proc. If someone knows the consequences of their actions, they should be able to remove those. The future defaults of these won't even be able to be changed. I updated my question to better explain this. +1 for a good overview.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff - the difference is, the settings always scripted are captured when the stored procedure is created - they are, in a very real way, part of the definition of the procedure, whereas any other settings are evaluated at runtime, when the procedure is executed.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my comment realizing those weren't good examples.

Comment: The more I think about it, your comment "part of the definition of the procedure" makes a lot of sense. Since it's in the definition table of the procedure itself, it's as important as the sql code itself. I totally disagree that either of these settings are *super duper important*, that I'd never want SSMS to stop scripting these, or that they should even be in that table since in the near future they will always be `ON`. But them being inserted because they are part of the code makes sense and explains why they can't be "turned off".

Comment: Only an opinion, but I think this is very annoying. We should be allowed to make the choice. It's like SELECT * always being expanded to a column list. I understand the reason behind it, but I'd like to be able to choose not to have it happen.